# set Select2 dropdown as readonly in some situation

Tags: jquery-select2

I used the jQuery select2 dropdown in my project.
I want to set readonly in the select2 dropdown in some situations. How can I set the select2 as readonly from an aspx.cs page (server side)?

And I want to insert the "Select All" checkbox for selecting all the options. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select2 responds to the disabled attribute on the `<select>` element.

If you run the the `<select>` element at the server you can just add this line of code, to the aspx.cs page (server side) when you want it to be read only.

`select2Element.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");`

Answer (score -1):

The following line set readonly or disable mode for select2 dropdown.
   **dropdownid.Disable=true;**

Comment: In Asp.net you can give like dropdownid.Disable = true;  in .cs page